# Rails best practices

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Can anyone help me with few indication about best way to do few things.
At this point I am in a situation where I have a task(.rake), and the code become so ugly that I need to split it out. So if I will create another file, probably a module with multiple classes and methods or just methods, where should I put the file (libs probably?)? (this file may be used by models as well). Also if I want to do the same or a module?

Any books, tutorials, articles, and opinions are welcomed.

Thank you

Comment: Pragmatic Programmers' Ruby (aka the Pickaxe Book) for the Ruby language itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [the Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rake) for an introduction - beyond that, there are many different [opinionated] resources on the matter, ie:

[Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/66-custom-rake-tasks)